# django forms make error appear beside field

Tags: python, django, django-forms

At my forms.py I have the following form where I want to check the input of the user against a trx_id at my database, the problem now is that the validation error does not get displayed beside the field, instead it always appears on top of the form, please see below:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

class TicketForm(forms.ModelForm):

error_messages = {
    'trx_id_mismatch': _('Transaction ID is Invalid'),
}
...
        self.fields['trx_id'].label = mark_safe('Transaction ID (Optional):')

    def clean(self):
        form_trx_id = self.cleaned_data.get('trx_id')
        trx_id = Transaction.objects.filter(trx_id=form_trx_id).exists()
        if form_trx_id:
            if not trx_id:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    self.error_messages['trx_id_mismatch'],
                    code='trx_id_mismatch',
                )
```

How can I make the validation error appaer beside the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is going to the forms general nonfield errors.

To add a specific error on a field, try

```
form.add_error('trx_id', 'trx_id_mismatch')
```

with translation example

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

form.add_error('trx_id', _('Transaction ID seems Invalid, please check'))
```

Comment: what is form in that context or in other words where to place it/get it at my code above?

Comment: Something like this is understandable to me:

                except forms.ValidationError as error:
                    self.add_error('some_field', error)

But only works in try execpt blocks i guess

Comment: oh sry, try `self.add_error('trx_id', 'trx_id_mismatch')`

Comment: Is the field called `trx_id` or is that a different models instance ?

Comment: Now the placement is right, so far so good, thanks!!!
But instead of the error message itself (the content) I get the name of the error message back "trx_id_mismatch"

This is how ich establish my error messages withhin the form:

    error_messages = {
        'trx_id_mismatch': _('Transaction ID seems Invalid, please check'),
    }

Comment: Yes the field is called trx_id, thats right

Comment: The second param in `add_error()` accepts a string, so the translations should recognize whatever the msgid  should be.

Comment: Okay, I first tought I could also pass the error_message inside it, my bad.